# wcf http binding vs dualhttp binding

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to build a http listener (webservice) with wcf. This listener is part of a bigger desktop application. This desktop application also invokes the http listener.

When the listener receives data it should be passed to the desktop application. I tried to build an httpbinding service and use the callback mechanism

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void OnDataReceived(Data data);
```

The problem is that I need wsDualhttpbinding because of the callback.

Do I really need to use the dualhttp to send data from one .NET app to another or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use HTTP?

Comment: the app receives data via http. So the listener part is indeed http

Comment: What I mean is why do you have to use http as transport? Can you use msmq for example? If so there are easier ways for you to do this.

Comment: I can use whatever I want but I assume I still best implement wcf for the http listener and then send the data with msmq to my backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have an event source which is exposed as a WCF service. The only way to for the service to send events to it's clients in real time is via a full duplex connection which means using either duathttp or dualtcp bindings.

However, using duplex bindings is complex at best. It would be simpler to allow the client to subscribe to the service and to then receive messages when events happen which the client is interested in.

This is much simpler than duplex bindings because there's no actual connection between client and service, only asynchronous messages.

While WCF provides bindings for msmq transport, it does not provide a binding with this kind of pub-sub support, so you can either code for this or you can use an open source messaging bus like [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need dual or duplex communication. HTTP by its very nature is a single direction protocol. The client has to invoke the server. The server has no way to talk to the client with out that.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to move the data to the desktop app since its both .net code?

Comment: Not if you have to use HTTP as your transport.

Comment: is this dualhttp standard conform? the http listener should work with different http calls

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a callback mechanism, as opposed to a polling mechanism, then yes, you need Dual binding as the WCF services needs to be able to both Send and Receive messages (as opposed to Receive and return responses)